# Mouse cursor moving in a square

Tags: mouse, battery, cursor

I tried using my wireless mouse yesterday (which wasn't used for roughly 2 months) on my desktop, and i noticed that i couldn't move it in any way, i could just press the two right and left buttons. The strange thing was that it started moving on its own, following a square pattern.
I've tried looking for some solutions online, but the few i found only mention an 'internal battery' (the one you recharge each time), while this mouse is only powered by disposable batteries.
Even using it on two different PCs or changing batteries result in the same behaviour, do you at least know the possible cause for this behaviour?
The mouse is from the Combo Scorpion Office Master (ITK829), and being a cheap mouse that comes with a keyboard it doesn't even have any sort of instructions with it, not even on their site.

Edit: I tried changing batteries, but it didn't work.

Comment: Combo ScoRPion Office Master, probably.

Comment: Did you change the batteries?

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, i tried but it didnt change anything

Comment: If another mouse works correctly, then this one can be junked.